How to handle ApexSOQLInjection for Dynamic Query
I have the following dynamic query:
String orderBy = ...; //Some value
String query = 'SELECT ' + String.join(fields, ', ') + ' FROM SObject__c WHERE Id IN :ids ORDER BY ' + orderBy + ' NULLS LAST';
List<SObject__c> sObjs = Database.query(query);

This line is flagged by PMD as a bad Apex SOQL Injection.
Is this a false positive? I don't see how I can change the string to make it pass the pmd rule.

Fundamentally this is because of the field list and order by field. It is very likely a false positive (depending how you generate the collection and get the order) but you could simply apply the String.escapeSingleQuotes around the string join and order by concatenation. It would, of course, result in invalid SOQL, but if there are already single quotes the query would be invalid anyway.
